# Web Farm Framework - Missing IIS features

Tags: iis, load-balancing, web-farm

I'm trying to install a web farm using Microsoft's Web Farm Framework 2.2. The server is Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

I followed a tutorial. Installed WFF from Web Platform Installer. However, I'm missing some key features in the "Server Farm" panel in IIS.

[image: This is how my setup looks like (image)]

> This is how my setup looks like

However, just like in the tutorial,

[image]

> I want it like this

How can I enable ALL the things, like Load Balancer, Health Test, Server Affinity etc? Thanks. The tutorial I used was this: weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That's [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting). Install it as well.

As a note, you might need to nuke your farm configuration if there are problems layering it atop the existing installation (which I assume is on a controller).

App Request Routing is the proxying module that integrates with Web Farm Framework, which is the Server Farming and app and platform provisioning module (as of WFF 2.0; WFF 1.0 was literally just "these servers exist in a farm, are online/offline, and here are their IPs").

ARR installs WFF 1.0 if you just install it; WFF doesn't install ARR if you install it, but ARR integrates nicely on a WFF Controller.

Comment: ARR was already installed. I tried using the repair function, and it seems that the controller installed a lot of things on the other servers. However, nothing changed. I removed each server, and removed the server farm, and created a new one and adding them again, with no luck. I also tried to uninstall WFF from both the controller and servers, and uninstalling the agent on the server. Reinstalled. No luck again. In addition, the servers are stuck on the AddServer command, so they aren't coming online. Completely clean servers with a fresh Windows install.

Comment: Is the controller a Primary as well? If so, don't do that. If not, I have no idea what's gone wrong (other than: did you close the InetMgr GUI between installations?).

Comment: The controller was a dedicated machine. So no, it wasn't a primary. I did close the UI. I'm under the impression that WFF isn't mature enough - it seems that a lot of people are having trouble with it. So I'm ditching it. Unless somebody knows what's wrong. Hopefully it will mature.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> -> <kbd>Administrative Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>IIS Manager</kbd>, not <kbd>Server Manager</kbd>.